# Why DateTime TryParse is returning date as {01/01/0001 00:00:00}?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am doing this

```
string[] formats = { "yyyy-MM-dd" };

DateTime outDate;

DateTime.TryParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToString(), 
                       formats,
                       new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                       DateTimeStyles.None, 
                       out outDate);

interfaceoperation.LogDate = outDate;
interfaceoperation.LogTime = outDate;
```

`LogDate` and `LogTime` are of type `DateTime`.

But it returns `outdate` value as `{01/01/0001 00:00:00}`.

Why?

Comment: Because `CultureInfo("en-US")` DateTiem format is **not** `yyyy-MM-dd` (but `MM/dd/yyyy`), so `DateTime.TryParseExact` returns `false` and **0** as a `DateTime`

Comment: so what should I do because i have to follow this format

Comment: Why are you parsing `DateTime.Now.ToString()`?

Comment: @Testingapps: you can either change format in `ToString` i.e. `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` or in `formats`: `string[] formats = { "yyyy-MM-dd", "M/d/yyyy" };`

Comment: because it only TryParseExact only accepts string

Comment: I cannot use any other format. So what should I do

Comment: What I mean is why not use `DateTime outDate = DateTime.Now`? Or is this just an example?

Comment: datetime.now is required since we logging dates. Also, i used DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),"yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: it works but not converting date to the specified format

Comment: A `DateTime` **has NO format in and of itself**. It's basically an `Int64` value counting Ticks since `MinValue`. The `string` *representation* of it however *does* have a format. To parse a `string` into a `DateTime`, you **must** use the format the `string` is in. Otherwise it's impossible. -- If you need to *represent* that `DateTime` value again, you can use the mandated format.

Comment: I have used DateTime.ParseExact and specified the same format but it doesn't save that format and returns another format

Comment: You should read what DateTime.TryParseExact does. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: The only time you should convert a `DateTime ` to a `string` is when you wish to display it using a certain format.  Otherwise, you should just keep it as a `DateTime`.  Please read the comment by @Corak again.

Comment: BTW. when you're debugging and hold your mouse over the filled `DateTime` variable, you'll probably see a string *representation* of the value using the format of the current culture of your system. But again, that's just a *representation*. In any other culture, that representation might look different. That's why it's important to precisely specify the culture and/or format, when you `ToString` that value again.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the format of the dates, we will have to add the correct format of your date.

```
 DateTime.TryParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToString(), DateTime.Now.GetDateTimeFormats(),
                             new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                             DateTimeStyles.None, out outDate);
```

or we will have to add the correct format of your date.

```
Or you can retrieve it directly from the wafer you use date:  
string[] formats = {"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", "M/d/yyyy h:mm tt",
                         "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss",
                         "M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt", "M/d/yyyy hh tt",
                         "M/d/yyyy h:mm", "M/d/yyyy h:mm",
                         "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm"};
```

Comment: It makes absolutely no sense to convert a `DateTime` to a `string` only to parse it back to a `DateTime`.  What is your first line of code trying to accomplish?

Comment: convert a DateTime to a string is in the example of the post, it can be replaced by another object of type DateTime .

Answer (score 0):

Well, `DateTime.TryParseExact` returns `false` and `DateTime.MinValue` (which is `01/01/0001 00:00:00`) whenever it *fails* to parse the given string.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.8

> When this method returns, contains the `DateTime` value equivalent to
>   the date and time contained in s, if the conversion **succeeded**, or
>   `MinValue` if the conversion **failed**. The conversion fails if either the
>   s or format parameter is null, is an empty string, or does not contain
>   a date and time that correspond to the pattern specified in format.
>   This parameter is passed uninitialized.

It seems, you want *more* `formats` to be mentioned:

```
   // Test value
   // Something like "10/08/2019 2:47:58 PM"
   string value = DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));

   ...

   string[] formats = { 
     "R",                  // RFC1123 e.g. 2019-10-08T14:39:47
     "yyyy-M-d",
     "yyyy-M-d H:m:s",
     "M/d/yyyy",           // en-US special: date only
     "M/d/yyyy H:m:s",     // en-US special: date and 24 hour time
     "M/d/yyyy h:m:s tt",  // en-US special: date and 12 hour time
   };       

   DateTime outDate;

   if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value, 
                              formats,
                              CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"),
                              DateTimeStyles.None, out outDate)) {
       // Parsing succeeded

       interfaceoperation.LogDate = outDate;
       interfaceoperation.LogTime = outDate;
   }
   else
   {
       // Parsing failed
   }
```